# Error in proxy configuration (ngx-admin with custom login) - ERROR GET http://localhost:4200/api/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, ngx-admin

I'm new to ngx-admin and now building an iot dashboard with that. I have made a custom login and path of my login auth folder is ngx-admin/src/app/auth. Now I want to make API calls for login.  I want to route my  "http://localhost:4200/api/login" to  "http://134.145.182.31:8001/api/login" For that I have created proxyconfig.json and made changes in angular.json and package.json files. But whenever I click on login button an error is thrown as "GET http://localhost:4200/api/login 404 (Not Found)".

Please don't reject this as a DUPLICATE QUESTION. Actually i have referred through almost all the link and forum, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem. Please help me.

proxyconfig.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://134.145.182.31:8001/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }        
    }
}
```

package.json

```
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json ",
```

angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxyconfig.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ngx-admin-demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

app.module.ts

```
NbAuthModule.forRoot({
      strategies: [
        NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
          name: 'email',
          baseEndpoint: 'api/',
          login: {
            endpoint: 'login',
          },
          token: {
            class: NbAuthJWTToken,
            key: 'token',
          }
        }),
      ],
      forms: {},
    }),
```

Expected:
On clicking login submit this local url ("http://localhost:4200/api/login" ) should call API server ("http://134.145.182.31:8001/api/login").

Comment: Are you doing ng serve or npm start?

Comment: yes.. i do npm start. 
Proxy is created as `Proxy created: /api -> http://134.145.182.31:8001/
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: ['error', 'close']`

Comment: Which url it actually calls?

Comment: It calls http://localhost:4200/api/login. and then shows an error http://localhost:4200/api/login 404 (Not Found)

Comment: proxyconfig.json is in src folder right?

Comment: Have you checked the API is it working?

Comment: Also i dont think a login request would be a GET request(as you described the error in question). You should be sending a post request with some credentials as JSON?

Comment: proxyconfig.json is outside src folder. near to package.json file.
API is working. I checked in postman.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I made it as a POST request.
My problem is solved. Actually i don't need a pathRewrite option in proxyconfig file. So i removed that. And is now working fine.

Comment: Awesome. All the best :)